# There is no Steam Manager Component in FizzySteamWorks

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamworks-api, unity3d-mirror

!SteamManager.Initialized produces an error saying that SteamManager is not a thing.

Plz help thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youl need to make a C# class called "SteamManager" and paste this code:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rlabrecque/SteamManager/master/SteamManager.cs

then add it to the scene where you are signing in

Answer (score 0):

youl need to make a C# class called "SteamManager" and paste this code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rlabrecque/SteamManager/master/SteamManager.cs

then add it to the scene where you are signing in

Comment: Duplicate of existing answer